# Using MarkerWithLabel on Google Maps hide the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently using the google maps marker with label control. I can dynamically assign a marker to the map, and have a label for that marker.

I have figured out how to hide the label however, I am at a bit of a loss on how to hide the icon and show the label.  Anyone with some suggestions on this?

```
markerWithLabel.setMap(null);
```

removes the marker and label, not just the marker.

Comment: can you share what you have done so far ?? what do you mean by label..

Comment: If you want to control them separately, you might need to modify that code.  Or put the labels on the map independently of the marker (i.e. use [InfoBox for the label](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html) and a normal google.maps.Marker for the marker)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very easy, just set a transparent image as the icon. Here I set a 1x1 transparent GIF - pixel_trans.gif - as Icon when the MarkerWithLabel is clicked :

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
...
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  this.setIcon('pixel_trans.gif');
});
```

Viola, the marker is hidden when it is clicked, but the label stand. It is *not* possible to hide the Icon and only show the label in the [current version](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html#MarkerWithLabelOptions) of MarkerWithLabel.

---

**Note**: You have to pass a valid image before this is going to work, eg an image that exists. Using `setIcon` with null or an invalid image will be ignored. An 1x1 transparent gif is imho an acceptable solution, since the user will have the experience that the marker is hidden, and will have a h*** of a trouble trying to click on it :)

Comment: @barry MSIH answer should be marked as the correct way

Answer (score 19):

I was able to hide the marker by setting the icon setting to an empty string " ".

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            icon: " ",
            position: location,
            draggable: true,
            raiseOnDrag: true,
            map: map,
            labelContent: z, 
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
        });
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Weird enough that it works - this seems to not request anything at all (where non existent paths will resolve in tons of 404 request).

Comment: This should be the correct answer, its easy and it works